# how to get entire current url in django

Tags: python, django

I have some trouble getting current url in django.
current url is 'https://localhost:8000/?#access_token=EAAJ0Dqh2BJ0BABNKWfkqmiIr3uWwKvpkVeCAVQTZBQSEFG87GKjXunsoofixxKS11ZCicElsZBRMKHL4Dk5nGeBa5lBkYvzw3YKrzZAyZAvhlvd1pAtxzZBPlD4PJaD7JFz4UCjOEIyo5ZCfyBIysva1PCK0XZAN7FpXCDRpDxlEVxtnN9RrbZAt26ZChHV3LRupoZD&data_access_expiration_time=1576926047&expires_in=7153'

i used several url getting functions such as request.get_full_path() and request.build_absolute_uri(), but they did only returns 'https://localhost:8000'

How can i get the string following '#' such as access_token?

Comment: There is a hash (`#`) in the URL, so that means it is not part of the path, this is used as an anchor point, so I guess you did the querystring encoding not correclty.

Comment: so you mean i can't get that?

Comment: you can encode the hash, but you can thus not pass a raw `#` into the querydict. The same holds for `!`, `*`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `:`, `@`, `&`, `=`, `+`, `$`, `,`, `/`, `?`, `[` and `]`. It is therefore *strongly* advisable *not* to do querystring generation yourself, but use some tool that can encode the keys and values for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part after the hash (`#`) is the [*fragment identifier* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). As is specified in the Wikipedia article:

> The fragment identifier functions differently to the rest of the URI: **its processing is exclusively client-sided** with no participation from the web server, though the server typically helps to determine the MIME type, and the MIME type determines the processing of fragments. When an agent (such as a web browser) requests a web resource from a web server, **the agent sends the URI to the server, but does not send the fragment**. Instead, the agent waits for the server to send the resource, and then the agent processes the resource according to the document type and fragment value.

So the webserver will never even obtain the fragment identifier. If you want to include a hash as part of the key of a querystring, you need to *encode* it with the [*percent-encoding* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), a hash is encoded to `%23`. Indeed, if you want the hash to be in the querydict, the URI should be:

```
https://localhost:8000/?%23access_token=EAAJ0Dqh2BJ0BABNKWfkqmiIr3uWwKvpkVeCAVQTZBQSEFG87GKjXunsoofixxKS11ZCicElsZBRMKHL4Dk5nGeBa5lBkYvzw3YKrzZAyZAvhlvd1pAtxzZBPlD4PJaD7JFz4UCjOEIyo5ZCfyBIysva1PCK0XZAN7FpXCDRpDxlEVxtnN9RrbZAt26ZChHV3LRupoZD&data_access_expiration_time=1576926047&expires_in=7153
```

If we generate such URI, then Django will parse this as:

```
>>> QueryDict('%23access_token=EAAJ0Dqh2BJ0BABNKWfkqmiIr3uWwKvpkVeCAVQTZBQSEFG87GKjXunsoofixxKS11ZCicElsZBRMKHL4Dk5nGeBa5lBkYvzw3YKrzZAyZAvhlvd1pAtxzZBPlD4PJaD7JFz4UCjOEIyo5ZCfyBIysva1PCK0XZAN7FpXCDRpDxlEVxtnN9RrbZAt26ZChHV3LRupoZD&data_access_expiration_time=1576926047&expires_in=7153')
<QueryDict: {'#access_token': ['EAAJ0Dqh2BJ0BABNKWfkqmiIr3uWwKvpkVeCAVQTZBQSEFG87GKjXunsoofixxKS11ZCicElsZBRMKHL4Dk5nGeBa5lBkYvzw3YKrzZAyZAvhlvd1pAtxzZBPlD4PJaD7JFz4UCjOEIyo5ZCfyBIysva1PCK0XZAN7FpXCDRpDxlEVxtnN9RrbZAt26ZChHV3LRupoZD'], 'data_access_expiration_time': ['1576926047'], 'expires_in': ['7153']}>
```

This is one of the main reasons why you should never do string processing yourself to encode a querystring. There are more characters that should be encoded when these are part of a key or value, like `!`, `*`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `;`, `:`, `@`, `&`, `=`, `+`, `$`, `,`, `/`, `?`, `[` and `]`. Although strictly speaking, you can encode these yourself. It is likely more safe to use a tool that has been tested effectively.

Comment: thank you for your response. i've understood what you explained. The problem is that the uri is generated from the third party. so how can i encode it?

Comment: @JingzhunLi: well you not encode it at server side, you have to encode it at the client side. For example by encoding the keys and values with `encodeURIComponent`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent