# How to correctly write url for #hashtag in Django

Tags: django

I want to insert data with modal form and show it on current page. Page already show data on table and modal form, now i need to add modal form to urls.py.

```
 path('viewpost/#add_data_Modal', views.createpost, name='createpost'),
```

Comment: The part after the `#` (including the `#`) is *never* send to the server: that is the fragment identifier: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048620/how-to-get-entire-current-url-in-django/58048704#58048704

Answer (score 1):

You could use a RedirectView for this:

```py
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import reverse


class ViewpostRedirectView(RedirectView):
    def get_redirect_url(*args, **kwargs):
        hash_part = "add_data_Modal"  # the data you want to add to the hash part
        return reverse("createpost") + "#{0}".format(hash_part)
```

Then in your urls.py you would have something lime this:

```py
path('viewpost/', views.createpost, name='createpost'),
path('viewpost/modal/', views.ViewpostRedirectView.as_view(), name='createpost_modal')
```

The **viewpost/modal/** url will redirect to the **viewpost/** url with the hash part appended to it.

Answer (score 1):

I find another simpler way to do it, I suggest passing the hashtag as a query string to the view then reverse redirect there, so

in `urls.py` keep it the simple

`path('', views.home, name='main-home')`

in `home` function in `views.py`

```
@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    hashtag = request.GET.get("hashtag", "")
    if hashtag:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("main-home") + "#{0}".format(hashtag))
    context = {}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

and in the html u can pass any hashtag you want

```
<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main-home' %}?hashtag=team" >Team</a>

<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'main-home' %}?hashtag=contact">Contact</a>
```